# I have a list that is dynamically updated, that I want to use as headings in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list, this list updates based on other factors and can change every day.

I want this list to append to the Headings of my DataFrame in Pandas
The DataFrame already has 3 headings that do not change, that come from another frame along with their data.

How do I parse a list so that each value makes a new column heading?

Thank you.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? By headings do you mean columns and you are attempting to add columns (changing the structure of the data)?

Comment: I had an empty list, then I have a getHeadings() function, which appends 15 values to the list. 
What I wanted to do, was just add them to either a new frame or my data source frame. 

In the end, I worked out that df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list) got me a new df, then I just concat them to a 3rd. not as neat as I would like, but its worked. Thanks for looking

Comment: so you're adding new rows of the same structure each day?

Comment: no, so the first 4 Columns are static, like "Name, Age, Job, Address"
But every day the next 15 Columns Change, "A, B, C" one day, and then E, F, G the next
within these columns are formula that give data based on other things.

Comment: if your data structure changes so often, maybe you should use something like json instead?

Comment: Thats an end goal, right now, I am stuck with Excel sheets from up on high. 
I got it to work in the end, just not neatly. :-)